# Now I want to generate Ledger statement for each client from my Transection Table through MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Table named as “Transection Table” in MS Access 2016 as follows:

[image: Screeen Shot of the transection Table]

Now I want to generate Ledger statement for each client from my Transection Table through MS Access Query which would generate Ledger statement report like Below:

[image: Sample Ledger Statement Report with Opening & Closing Blance]

Please anyone do this for me by suggesting appropriate SQL query and report. Your assistance will be much appreciated !! Thanks In Advance !!
Ashik
Dhaka, Bangladesh

Comment: please write your query tried. you can review stackoverflow tour and help center for give best feedback.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  Images are discouraged; text tables and SQL/DB fiddles are encouraged.

Comment: That is what I am asking for, and you are asking me to do so..!! I am new in ms access query writing, therefore, I  raised a requirement. So that based on that query I can solve other similar types of queries. However, suggest me a proper query, if you are willing to help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff,  Table data is given, and I want to generate a ledger statement showing 'client ID' wise opening & closing balance, that's it...

Comment: This is a common topic. Search web and will find many discussions. One approach uses DSum() to get Start Balance in report or group header and RunningSum property of textbox on report to calculate daily balance.

Answer (score 0):

using the approach of putting all the columns you need in the report source:  Note I'm assuming bills are positive and payments are negative.

[image]

```
SumDebits: DSum("Amount","Transections","ClientID = " & [ClientID] & " AND TransectionDate < #" & [TransectionDate] & "# AND TransectionType = 'bill' ")
SumPayments: DSum("Amount","Transections","ClientID = " & [ClientID] & " AND TransectionDate < #" & [TransectionDate] & "# AND TransectionType = 'payment' ")
OpeningBalance: Nz([SumDebits],0)-Nz([SumPayments],0)
ClosingBalance: [OpeningBalance]+IIf([TransectionType]="bill",[Amount],-[Amount])
```

note TransectionType is a string so bill is enclosed in single quotes.  Note the hashtags around the date.  since the query has all the columns needed for the report just use the menu to make the report.
[image]

Comment: @ mazoula, Thnak a Ton!!

Comment: @ mazoula, Just one more question, If I want to add some parameter in place of the Client ID and Transaction date then what that would be?

Comment: if you want to filter by it and it is in the transections table just add it to the filter string in the dsums.  if it is in the transections table and you want to include it just check show.